# Significance value in Hypothesis testing

Tags: hypothesis-testing

A builder claims that heat pumps are installed in $70\%$ of all homes being constructed today in Chennai. Would you agree with this claim if a random survey of new homes in this city showed that $8$ out of $15$ had heat pumps installed? Use a $10\%$ level of significance.

Here the null hypothesis(H$_0$) is $p = 0.7$ and alternative hypothesis(H$_A$) : $p \neq 0.7$. So, it is a both-ended test.

I want to compute the value of the type-1 error using the definition P ($A^c$ | $H_0$ is true), where A is the acceptance set, but I cannot formulate it correctly. How do we define the acceptance set?

I have completed the following two steps.

$\bullet$ Reject $H_0$ if $\big|T-10.5\big| > c$.

$\bullet$ P($A^c$ | $H_0$ is true ) = $\text{P} (T > c+10.5 \,\, \text{or} \,\, T < 10.5-c \,\, | \,\, p = 0.7 \,)= \text{P} (T > c+10.5 \,\,| \,\, p =0.7) + P(\,\, T < 10.5-c \,\, | \,\, p = 0.7 \,)$.

The above step is creating confusion. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi @math, welcome to CV. Try searching for "binomial hypothesis test" - e.g. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/513031/binomial-hypothesis-testing-finding-p-value

Comment: The most important pedagogical aspect of this question is the formulation of the alternative hypothesis, so I suggest you give that more consideration before you do any calculations.

Comment: @whuber Yes, there is a mistake in formulating the alternative hypothesis. We can check individually, but I am unsure if we can create sets like normal distributions in terms of c.

Comment: Please add the [tag:self-study] tag & read its 
[wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us what you understand thus far, what 
you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll provide hints to 
help you get unstuck. Please make these changes as just 
posting your homework & hoping someone will do it for you 
is grounds for closing.